# how to Add 1 year to startdate to get the end date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

want a output like below

if Start Date is "01-03-2016" the End date should be "28-02-2017"
if Start Date is "10-04-2016" the End date should be "09-04-2017"

I tried below code

```
if (dat <= 31 && dat >= 1 && month <= 12 && month >= 1) {

            var expiryDate = new Date(n1, month - 1, dat);

            expiryDate.setFullYear(expiryDate.getFullYear() + 1);
            var day = ('0' + expiryDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var month1 = ('0' + (expiryDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var year = expiryDate.getFullYear();
            var month = getMonthName(month1);

            var wholeenddate = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
```

but it's not produce desired output.Please Help to solve it.

Comment: you want to add 365 days to the current date?

Comment: If i add 365 days then in case if my date is "01-03-2016" then it will give end date "01-03-2017"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **364 days** to your date

For example

```
var d = new Date("2016-03-01");
d.setDate(d.getDate()+364); //outputs 28-02-2017
```

and

```
var d = new Date("2016-04-10");
d.setDate(d.getDate()+364); //outputs 09-04-2017
```

or Just **add 1 year** and **sub 1 day**.

```
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
```

Now it will match your output just the same even for leap year :)

**Demo**

```js
var d = new Date("2016-03-01");
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
document.body.innerHTML += d.toString();

document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";


d = new Date("2016-04-10");
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
document.body.innerHTML += d.toString();
```

Comment: What happens in a leap year? ;)

Comment: @piyush what should be the output in case of 2016-01-01

Comment: output should be 2016-12-31

Comment: @piyush check the updated code at the end, it gives the output you are looking for

Comment: how can i do it same in php?

Answer (score 2):

There's a convenient library to help with this sort of thing - [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) (14k zipped).

```
var startDate = moment('01-03-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
var endDate = startDate.clone();
endDate.add(1, 'years').subtract('1', 'days');
console.log(endDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

3 ways to do this.

```
 // Add hours
 var today = new Date();
 today.setHours(today.getHours()+24*364);

 // Add days
 var nextyearDate = new Date();
 nextyearDate.setDate(today.getDate()+364);

 // More reliable way : Add year & subtract a day.. Hope this works...! Works for 01/01/2016
 var nextDate = new Date();
 nextDate.setYear(nextDate.getFullYear()+1);
 nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()-1);
```

Comment: @epascarello.. thanks for noticing this. I have edited.. hope the latest  answer works